# Hair particles: Unwanted, irrevertable mirroring!

Tags: particles, mirror, hair

I've been styling hair particles for an asymmetrical look. To speed up my workflow, I turned on x-mirror in the particle edit tools panel when working on individual strands, then turning it off to create asymmetry. However, I left the x-mirror option on when I exited particle edit mode, and now whenever I return to particle edit mode, the entire system is forced into symmetry and half my work is undone!

[image: hair particles in object mode]

[image: hair particles in particle edit mode]

Ctrl+z does *not* work here. What can I do to avoid losing half my work?